# PHP+AJAX with MySQL - Query every 2 seconds, too many in TIME_WAIT

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a basic HTML file, using jQuery's ajax, that is connecting to my polling.php script every 2 seconds.

The polling.php simply connections to mysql, checks for ID's newer than my hidden, stored current ID, and then echo's if there is anything new. Since the javascript is connecting every 2 seconds, I am getting thousands of connections in TIME_WAIT, just for my client. This is because my script is re-connecting to MySQL over and over again. I have tried mysql_pconnect but it didn't help any.

Is there any way I can get PHP to open 1 connection, and continue to query using it? Instead of reconnecting every single time and making all these TIME_WAIT connections. Unsure what to do here to make this work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up doing basic Long Polling. I made a simple PHP script to to an infinite while loop, and it queries every 2 seconds. If it finds something new, it echoes it out, and breaks the loop. My jquery simply ajax connects to it, and waits for a reponse; on reponse, it updates my page, and restarts the polling. Very simple!

PS, the Long Polling method also reduces browser memory issues, as well as drastically reduces the TIME_WAIT connections on the server.

Comment: This gets a good amount of views, so I thought I'd add a bit more.  You make a while loop in PHP, and make it break after 15-30 seconds.  I suggest staying below 30 seconds for timeout reasons.  In the while loop you can query a database every second, or memcached, or maybe poll a simple text file via filemtime() to see if it's changed.  You can use touch() on the file when something new happens to update its time.  If theres something new, echo "NEW" and exit the script.  If theres nothing, after the loop echo "NONE" or something and exit.  Then in your Javascript, check for "NEW" and "NONE".

Answer (score 0):

There's no trivial way of doing this, as pconnect doesn't work across multiple web page calls. However, some approaches to minimise the database throughput would be:

1. Lower the polling time. (2 seconds is perhaps a bit excessive?)
2. Have a "master" PHP script that runs every 'n' seconds, extracts the data from the database and saves it in the appropriate format (serialised PHP array, XML, HTML data, etc.) in the filesystem. (I'd recommend writing to a temp file and then renaming over the existing one to minimise any partial file collection issues.) The Ajax requested PHP page would then simply use the information in this data file.

In terms of executing the master PHP script, you could either use cron or simply let the user who first requests the page when the contents of file is deemed too stale. (You could use the data file's timestamp for this purpose via the [filemtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function.) I'd personally use the latter approach, as cron is overkill for this purpose.

You could take this even further and use [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) instead of a flat file, etc. if so required. (That said, it would perhaps be an over-complex solution at this stage of affairs.)

Comment: "(serialised PHP array, XML, HTML data, etc.)". Isn't memcached easy enough to use here?

Comment: @Keyo Pretty much depends on whether or not memcached is available on his PHP installation. :-) As such, I mentioned the basic filesystem approach first.

Comment: Memcached doesn't just solve the issue though.  The ideal solution would be a comet server, but I haven't figured out how to have a comet server query my database for me.  For now I'll up the interval to 5 seconds I suppose, though that kills anything close to real-time.

Comment: @Ryan - I'd recommend using master PHP master script approach as well - this will radically lower the number of polling queries to two or three every 'n' seconds.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  I actually ended up doing basic Long Polling.  I made a simple PHP script to to an infinite while loop, and it queries every 2 seconds.  If it finds something new, it echoes it out, and breaks the loop.  My jquery simply ajax connects to it, and waits for a reponse; on reponse, it updates my page, and restarts the polling.  Very simple!

Comment: PS, the Long Polling method also reduces browser memory issues, as well as drastically reduces the TIME_WAIT connections on the server.